# Devise edit account information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

When I go to the `edit_user_registration_path` provided by Devise I have fields such as email and username **pre-filled**.

I want to create custom user profile page with the similar form for edit user information containing additional fields of dependent model. And I want fields be **pre-filled**.
How should I do it properly?

The default form provided by Devise:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off" %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Update" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested attributes

In your devise user model, if you have other dependent models, you can add a relationship between those models, like `has_many` and `belongs_to`. The do this:

Devise user model:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :name_of_other_model`

Then in  your form you can use fields_for. [fields_for docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)

Here's also a great railscast of this [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's pretty much what I want. And what about pre-filled fields? When I place the form above in my custom view the fields are not pre-filled unlike on default devise user edit page.

Comment: If the user that your editing exists already, then in your edit view, the fields that tie back to the database will be filled. In that screencast it was all about creating new model objects, but if you notice when he goes back to edit the questions, the info is still there in the editable text fields. If you want something in those fields at the time of creating the user then add methods in your model named after the attributes that you want data in.  If you give me something specific your looking for as far as data you want to add, I can update my answer with that info.